# Algorithm To Find Minimum Distance Between Two Triangles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, language-agnostic

This might be better asked on Math.SE, but I'll try here first:

If I have two arbitrary triangles in 3D space, how can I determine the minimum distance between them? See the following: [image] 
It's difficult to see in the image, but triangle BAC is entirely in the positive Z-plane, whereas triangle DFE is entirely in the negative Z-plane. The normals for both triangles are parallel to the X-Y plane. The minimum distance between them is probably the distance between the two points I've plotted (H and G).

Assuming the triangles are not co-planar, I know that one of the points representing the smallest distance between the two triangles must lie on either a vertex or along an edge for one of the triangles. For the other triangle, it can lie anywhere on the plane, including along the edges or vertices.

I don't actually need the minimum distance itself - ultimately, all I need to find is whether or not the triangles are within some epsilon of each other.

One thing I've tried is simply sampling the surfaces and applying a fast epsilon test to see if any points from one triangle are within epsilon of any points on the other, but this is too slow for my application. It seems to me that this should have a direct analytical solution, but I haven't been able to find anything about this problem at all.

Comment: You can find triangle distance calculation routines in [PQP - Proximity Query Pack](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/SSV/).

Comment: Can you precise the assumption "Both are perpendicular to the X-Y plane" ? Is it just that their normal lie in X-Y ?

Comment: Following https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213165/find-shortest-distance-between-lines-in-3d , find distance between all the lines of triangles, adjust to the triangle borders  and choose minimum.

Comment: @AxelKemper I'll look into PQP. The source code for TriDist() is pretty dense, so it'll take me some time to translate it into something useful.

Comment: @Vince Sorry, you're right; that's confusing. The opposite actually, their normals would be parallel to the X-Y plane (meaning that the body of the triangles are perpindicular to the X-Y plane). I'll edit the question.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov That won't work in general. It's possible that one triangle has a vertex which is sitting nearly at the center of the other triangle. If I only test the edges, I would miss that minimum distance between one triangle's vertex and the other triangle's plane.

Comment: Well with the "normal parallele to XY" and "half plan separation" conditions, the case you describe cannot happen and the closest points to each other have to be on edges. You even can take off one or two edges of each triangle to reduce the test.

Comment: @Vince Well, yeah, obviously, but this is just a simple example for visualization purposes... I need a solution that works in the general case

Comment: @AxelKemper So I translated that code, and it seems to work exactly like I needed. If you roll that into an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise, I can write-up an explanation for how it works and post that.

Comment: @A.Comer I would favor to see the (pseudo) code you extracted from PQP, Should be interesting for others as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in Axel's comment, an implementation can be found at [PQP - Proximity Query Pack](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/SSV/) (in particular, the TriDist.cpp file). However, there are no accompanying citations for the algorithm, nor can I find anything on Eric Larsen, who apparently wrote it (in fact, [this 2014 paper](http://jcgt.org/published/0003/04/05/paper.pdf) also mentioned that they couldn't find any publication for the algorithm, besides the PQP source code).

---

The gist of the algorithm is pretty simple:

First, find the minimum distance between each pair of edges (9 total combinations). Here, PQP uses the following algorithm:

[Vladimir J. Lumelsky, *On fast computation of distance between line segments*. Information Processing Letters, no. 21, pages 55-61, 1985.](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/octrope/trunk/doc/lumelsky.pdf)

Imagine the following scenario (shown in 2-D for simplicity):
[image]

Triangle ABC on the left, and triangle DEF on the right. Let's imagine we were looking at edges AB and EF - we would find that the vertices B and F define the closest points between the two line segments. We then draw two planes at the closest points which are perpendicular to the connecting vector (see below):
[image]

Note that I've colored the vertices of the two edges we're comparing blue, whereas the off-edge vertices are now green. We now look at the off-edge vertices and check if they are on opposing sides of the two planes (thanks to Adam in the comments for clarification on this). Because vertex D is between the two planes, we know that we have not found the true minimum distance between the two triangles.

Now, if we look at edges BC and DE, we see the following arrangement:
[image]

Because both off-edge vertices are on opposing sides of the two planes, we can guarantee that we've found the minimum distance between the two triangles.

---

In 2-D, it's guaranteed that the minimum distance is along the edges of both triangles, but this is not the case in 3-D. If the above checks didn't find the minimum distance (i.e., no pair of edges passed the plane test), one of the following cases must be true:

1. One of the closest points is a vertex of one triangle and the other closest point is on the face of the other triangle
2. The triangles intersect
3. An edge of one triangle is parallel to the face of the other triangle
4. One or both triangles are degenerate

First, you must check case 1:

Project the points from the first triangle onto the second and take the dot product of the projected points with the first triangle's normal. All of the dot products should have the same sign (if not, swap which triangles you operate on). Then, find the vertex with the shortest projection and check that its projection actually lies on the surface of the other triangle. If it does, you've found your two points (the vertex you're looking at, as well as its projection onto the other triangle).

Otherwise, it must fall into cases 2 - 4.

If the two triangles were shown to be disjoint in the previous checks, then it's either case 3 or 4. Regardless, simply use the minimum points found in the first test. Otherwise, it must be case 2, in which case the minimum distance is zero.

Comment: Wow! You put quite an effort in your self-answer!

Comment: This [paper](http://www.ikonstantinos.com/Konstantinos_Krestenitis_ACME2015.pdf) might be of interest.

Comment: ha, well I haven't been able to find any other explanations online, so hopefully this will help someone in the future

Comment: Hi. I was running into some issues with what is meant by "outside" because I found out that the two off-edge-vertices can both be outside of the region between the two planes while the edges in question don't hold the shortest distance. https://imgur.com/a/zLfFkW4. What is meant by "outside" is that both of these off-edge vertices in question must be in the correct opposing sides outside the region between the planes. Just thought I'd emphasize this.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that’s an interesting (and probably common?) case I hadn’t considered. I’ve edited the answer to clarify that the vertices need to be on opposing sides of that slab

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is amazingly well explained. Those looking for a code can refer to [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA-Omniverse/PhysX/blob/a2af52eb6a2532bd2bc583ef8ead9c81c9222af1/physx/source/geomutils/src/distance/GuDistanceTriangleTriangle.cpp) implementation in Nvidia's Physx library.

I'm going to point out implementation details of some aspects of the algorithm:

- For the main check, i.e. "off-edge vertices are on opposing sides of the two planes", nvidia does this:

  ```
               PxU32 id = i+2;
               if(id>=3)
                   id-=3;
               PxVec3 Z = p[id] - cp;
               float a = Z.dot(V);
               id = j+2;
               if(id>=3)
                   id-=3;
               Z = q[id] - cq;
               float b = Z.dot(V);

               if((a<=0.0f) && (b>=0.0f))
                   return V.dot(V);
  ```

Here `p[id]` is the off-edge vertex of triangle A, `cp` is the closest point found on A, `V` the vector connecting that closest point to closest point on triangle B (i.e. `V=cq - cp`). `a=Z.dot(V)<=0.0` means off-edge vertex is outside the stab defined by those two red planes. Same is repeated for triangle B, `(a<=0.0f) && (b>=0.0f)` ensures these vertices are on opposite side of the plane, and the function returns.

If this doesn't return after checking each pair of edges, we try to check for the first edge case ("One of the closest points is a vertex of one triangle and the other closest point is on the face of the other triangle"):

- Compute the face normal of a triangle (say ABC), and check it is not degenerate (magnitude of normal `snl` > 0). If not so, find the dot product of the face normal and vector DA, EB, and CF. (`SV` contains the edge vectors for ABC). All the dot products should have similar sign in case of this vertex-face case (two `if` conditions below). This also finds the vertex (`index`) that's closest.
  [image]
- Lastly, check the projection of the closest vertex on the face plane lies within the triangle. If the closest vertex is `P`, find `PA, PB, PC` (`V`s below), find cross product of face normal with each with triangle edges (`Z` below), and ensure their dot products are all > 0.
  [image]
- If dot products are > 0, return P and it's projection on the face of ABC.
  [image]

Repeat this for both triangles. If the function doesn't return yet, this means either edge case 2 or 4 from the answer above. Rest should be easy to follow.

Comment: excuse me for using screenshots, had trouble with formatting