# How to get the shortest distance between two triangles in 3D, given their vertices' position? (In Python)

Tags: python, vector, 3d, geometry

I have **triangle_a**, defined by 3d position vectors **p1, p2, and p3**, and **triangle_b**, defined by different 3d position vectors **q1, q2, q3**. I would like to know an *efficient* algorithm for finding the shortest distance between the surfaces of the two triangles.

Coding platform preferred: *Python 3.8*

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possibly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602907/algorithm-to-find-minimum-distance-between-two-triangles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm To Find Minimum Distance Between Two Triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602907/algorithm-to-find-minimum-distance-between-two-triangles)